# php session lost using http2 preload

Tags: php, session, http2, slim-3

I'm experiencing a problem using HTTP/2 push preload with the php session: when I open a page that use a preload header feature, the session is lost/reset. The application code is open source, here is where I set the Link header:
https://github.com/SergiX44/XBackBone/blob/master/app/Controllers/UploadController.php#L107

```
...
$url = urlFor("/$args[userCode]/$args[mediaCode]/raw");
$response = $response->withHeader('Link', "<{$url}>; rel=preload; as={$type}");
...
```

[image: request]

[image: raw request headers]

As you can see in the pictures the HTTP/2 push is actually working, but the "pushed" resource is resetting the session (the "raw" request in this case is an image, served by PHP). Why is that happening?

Comment: What do you mean it’s resetting the session? If “raw” is an image why is it saying it’s text/html?

Comment: Means that the current session is invalidated, as shown in the request the header is set with a new session id. The raw image returns a text/html because a the server throw a 403 forbidden, because the image is visible only at logged users (and because the session is invalidated).

Comment: And this happen only if I enable the HTTP/2, because when is not enable it works without problems. I don't understand why the pushed resource is invalidating the current session. In that scenario described in the answer, if I go back to the previous page I'll be redirected to the login page, because the session "reset".

Comment: Ok. I thought you meant the HTTP/2 session was invalidated (i.e. the session was dropped). Now I understand your problem I can explain this. Answer coming up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache HTTP/2 module [only certain headers are copied on pushed request](https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/152).

The full list of headers is listed i[n the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html#push)

> Apache will look at the original request (the one that triggered the PUSH) and copy the following headers over to PUSH requests: `user-agent, accept, accept-encoding, accept-language, cache-control.`
>
> All other headers are ignored. Cookies will also not be copied over. PUSHing resources that require a cookie to be present will not work. This can be a matter of debate. But unless this is more clearly discussed with browser, let's err on the side of caution and not expose cookie where they might oridinarily not be visible.

Note how it explicitly calls out that cookies will not be sent. Therefore there is no session and so your PHP app is setting a new one.

HTTP/2 push is intended to send safe, cacheable resources and Apache has chosen to interpret this has non-authenticated resources. Therefore unless you can serve your pushed resource without requiring cookies, you should not push it.

You can use the `preload` header with the `nopush` attribute to avoid pushing it, but still have the browser request it with high priority. As the browser is requesting it, it will send the appropriate cookies and all should work. It may not be quiet as fast as push but it’s often good enough. Additionally as browsers are aware of their cache, using preload instead of push is often recommended anyway. [Push is complicated to get right](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/h2-push-tougher-than-i-thought/) - and not just because of the issue you’ve spotted here.

Comment: Thank you for your this great explanation, I'll avoid to push the resource when a session is created adding the nopush attribute.